# Javascript in IE vs Firefox error

Tags: javascript

`**<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"`>**

In the above dtd the **calender** program is working **fine** in **IE 8, Chrome, safari, opera** but in firefox it makes problem of displaying all the values as 1.

**The script for calendar program i give below please check and help me**

```
<body>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
span.label {color:black;width:30;height:16;text-align:center;margin-top:0;background:#ffF;font:bold 13px Arial}
span.c1 {cursor:hand;color:black;width:30;height:16;text-align:center;margin-top:0;background:#ffF;font:bold 13px Arial}
span.c2 {cursor:hand;color:red;width:30;height:16;text-align:center;margin-top:0;background:#ffF;font:bold 13px Arial}
span.c3 {cursor:hand;color:#b0b0b0;width:30;height:16;text-align:center;margin-top:0;background:#ffF;font:bold 12px Arial}
-->
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- This script and many more are available free online at -->
<!-- The JavaScript Source!! http://javascript.internet.com -->

<!-- Begin
function maxDays(mm, yyyy){
var mDay;
    if((mm == 3) || (mm == 5) || (mm == 8) || (mm == 10)){
        mDay = 30;
    }
    else{
        mDay = 31
        if(mm == 1){
            if (yyyy/4 - parseInt(yyyy/4) != 0){
                mDay = 28
            }
            else{
                mDay = 29
            }
        }
  }
return mDay;
}
function changeBg(id){
    if (eval(id).style.backgroundColor != "yellow"){
        eval(id).style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
    }
    else{
        eval(id).style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff"
    }
}
function writeCalendar(){
var now = new Date
var dd = now.getDate()
var mm = now.getMonth()
var dow = now.getDay()
var yyyy = now.getFullYear()
var arrM = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")
var arrY = new Array()
    for (ii=0;ii<=4;ii++){
        arrY[ii] = yyyy - 2 + ii
    }
var arrD = new Array("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat")

var text = ""
text = "<form name=calForm>"
text += "<table border=1>"
text += "<tr><td>"
text += "<table width=100%><tr>"
text += "<td align=left>"
text += "<select name=selMonth onChange='changeCal()'>"
    for (ii=0;ii<=11;ii++){
        if (ii==mm){
            text += "<option value= " + ii + " Selected>" + arrM[ii] + "</option>"
        }
        else{
            text += "<option value= " + ii + ">" + arrM[ii] + "</option>"
        }
    }
text += "</select>"
text += "</td>"
text += "<td align=right>"
text += "<select name=selYear onChange='changeCal()'>"
    for (ii=0;ii<=4;ii++){
        if (ii==2){
            text += "<option value= " + arrY[ii] + " Selected>" + arrY[ii] + "</option>"
        }
        else{
            text += "<option value= " + arrY[ii] + ">" + arrY[ii] + "</option>"
        }
    }
text += "</select>"
text += "</td>"
text += "</tr></table>"
text += "</td></tr>"
text += "<tr><td>"
text += "<table border=1>"
text += "<tr>"
    for (ii=0;ii<=6;ii++){
        text += "<td align=center><span class=label>" + arrD[ii] + "</span></td>"
    }
text += "</tr>"
aa = 0
    for (kk=0;kk<=5;kk++){
        text += "<tr>"
        for (ii=0;ii<=6;ii++){
            text += "<td align=center><span id=sp" + aa + " onClick='changeBg(this.id)'>1</span></td>"
            aa += 1
        }
        text += "</tr>"
    }
text += "</table>"
text += "</td></tr>"
text += "</table>"
text += "</form>"
document.write(text)
changeCal()
}
function changeCal(){
var now = new Date
var dd = now.getDate()
var mm = now.getMonth()
var dow = now.getDay()
var yyyy = now.getFullYear()
var currM = parseInt(document.calForm.selMonth.value)
var prevM
    if (currM!=0){
        prevM = currM - 1
    }
    else{
        prevM = 11
    }
var currY = parseInt(document.calForm.selYear.value)
var mmyyyy = new Date()
mmyyyy.setFullYear(currY)
mmyyyy.setMonth(currM)
mmyyyy.setDate(1)
var day1 = mmyyyy.getDay()
    if (day1 == 0){
        day1 = 7
    }
var arrN = new Array(41)
var aa
    for (ii=0;ii<day1;ii++){
        arrN[ii] = maxDays((prevM),currY) - day1 + ii + 1
    }
    aa = 1
    for (ii=day1;ii<=day1+maxDays(currM,currY)-1;ii++){
        arrN[ii] = aa
        aa += 1
    }
    aa = 1
    for (ii=day1+maxDays(currM,currY);ii<=41;ii++){
        arrN[ii] = aa
        aa += 1
    }
    for (ii=0;ii<=41;ii++){
        eval("sp"+ii).style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
    }
var dCount = 0
    for (ii=0;ii<=41;ii++){
        if (((ii<7)&&(arrN[ii]>20))||((ii>27)&&(arrN[ii]<20))){
            eval("sp"+ii).innerHTML = arrN[ii]
            eval("sp"+ii).className = "c3"
        }
        else{
            eval("sp"+ii).innerHTML = arrN[ii]
            if ((dCount==0)||(dCount==6)){
                eval("sp"+ii).className = "c2"
            }
            else{
                eval("sp"+ii).className = "c1"
            }
            if ((arrN[ii]==dd)&&(mm==currM)&&(yyyy==currY)){
                eval("sp"+ii).style.backgroundColor="#90EE90"
            }
        }
    dCount += 1
        if (dCount>6){
            dCount=0
        }
    }
}
//  End -->
</script>
</body>

<div>
                    &nbsp<script type="text/javascript">writeCalendar()</script>
                    </div>
```

Comment: You need to make this readable.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sorry, but this is *way* too much code. You should isolate your problem some more, down to the line or at least region where variables get set differently from what you want.

Comment: There is so much wrong with that code that I don't know where to begin. In all seriousness, throw it away and find a reputable source to learn from.

Comment: Unrelated: The leap year rule since 1582 for the Gregorian calendar is: A year is a leap year, if it is dividable by 4, unless it is dividable by 100. But if it is dividable by 400 it is one anyway.

Comment: Conclusion: You need a different script.

Answer (score 1):

The script is not supposed to work with that doctype. It produces HTML code, not XHTML code.

Also, the script uses `eval` to find elements instead of `document.getElementById`, which only works in IE and browsers that try to emulate it. The `eval` function has it's rare uses, but this is not a good use of it. I am surprised if you only have that single problem that you describe.